# For loop Count in django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to display a number of the count in Django template in sequence.

Like if for loop iterate 5 time then it should print ***0,1,2,3,4*** in Django template.

`users` contains string which I pass from ***views.py***

```
{% for user in users %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            FOR LOOP ITERATE COUNT
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ user.first_name }}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Lalit But how would that allow them to access `user` at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can user `{{forloop.counter0}}`:

```
{% for user in users %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{forloop.counter0}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ user.first_name }}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```